# All possible pattern match and replacement

Tags: pattern-matching

Given a list, how to get all possible new lists replacing a matched pattern with a new pattern (every time only one replacement)?

For example, I have a list like this `{0, 1, 0, 1}`. I want to first find all the `{0, 1}` in it. Then each time I replaced one and only one of them with `{1, 0}` to get a new list. So in this example the result should be `{{1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0}}`, each sublist of which is a list replacing one of the matched pattern `{0, 1}` with `{1, 0}`.

I try `{0, 1, 0, 1} /. {x___, PatternSequence[0, 1], y___} -> {x, 1, 0, y}` but this only gives one list `{1, 0, 0, 1}`, not whole possible lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [ReplaceList](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceList.html):

> ReplaceList[*expr*, *rules*]
>      attempts to transform the entire expression *expr* by applying a rule or list 
>      of rules **in all possible ways**, and **returns a list** of the results obtained.

```
lst = {0, 1, 0, 1};

ReplaceList[{x___, PatternSequence[0, 1], y___} :> {x, 1, 0, y}] @ lst
```

> {{1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0}}

Comment: Seems this doesn't give the desired result? :)

Comment: @atoman,  fixed now.

Comment: Looks nice!! thx:)

Answer (score 1):

My answer may be verbose:

```
Table[ReplacePart[#, 
Thread[SequencePosition[#, {0, 1}][[i]] -> {1, 0}]], {i, 
Length[SequencePosition[#, {0, 1}]]}] &@{0, 1, 0, 1}
```

> {{1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0}}

another test

```
Table[ReplacePart[#, 
Thread[SequencePosition[#, {0, 1}][[i]] -> {1, 0}]], {i, 
Length[SequencePosition[#, {0, 1}]]}] &@{0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1}
```

> {{1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0}}